# How to convert appx file to .msi file?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-installer, setup-project

I have created a universal windows application.while building my application i am getting .appx package file, but i need a build in .msi file. Is it possible to build my application in .msi file or any alternatives.

Comment: Why do you need an MSI?

Comment: Its my clients requirement,I think .msi is better than appx package file to install and use.@PeterTorr-MSFT

Comment: AppX deployment is actually one of the benefits of UWP since it is more reliable for install / uninstall / update than MSI was.

Comment: @Peter Torr :Even I have encountered the same issue. Is there any way where I can create a msi package ? Any tool that can do that ?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Do we have anything available that can help me coverting APPX package to MSI ? My client needs the MSI so that he can distribute

Comment: What technology are they using to distribute? What is stopping them distributing the appx?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

But you can distribute your Appx file even outside the Store, as a stand-alone package, just like a executable one (like .exe or .msi).

Of course, users will need Win 10 to execute it.